# Momentary interruptions while streaming mp3 from url source

Tags: c#

I am working on streaming mp3 from url source for a few days.It almost works good except a small problem. The problem is that there is some momentary interruptions while playing mp3. I couldnt figure out why this happening. I need help and my code is like that. Sorry it's too long but maybe you want to try.

```
enter code here
```

private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string url = "http://freedownloads.last.fm/download/569264057/Get%2BGot.mp3";
        bool playingStarted = false;

        WaveStream str;
        WaveFormat format = GetWaveFormat(url);

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        int contentLength=(int)resp.ContentLength;

        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

        BufferedWaveProvider provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
        provider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[format.SampleRate];
        byte[] totalBuffer = new byte[contentLength];
        byte[] mp3StreamBuffer = new byte[format.SampleRate];

        int bytesRead = 0, totalBytes=0;
        int decBytes = 0;
        long skipTo = 0;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, totalBuffer, totalBytes, bytesRead);

                totalBytes += bytesRead;

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar2.Value = (int)(totalBytes * 100.0 / contentLength); });

                if (totalBytes < format.AverageBytesPerSecond) 
                    continue;

                str = new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream(totalBuffer));

                str.Position = skipTo;

                while ((decBytes = str.Read(mp3StreamBuffer, 0, mp3StreamBuffer.Length)) > 0) 
                {
                    provider.AddSamples(mp3StreamBuffer, 0, decBytes);
                }

                skipTo = str.Position;

                if (playingStarted)
                {
                    playingStarted = false;
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {

                        play.Init(provider);
                        play.Play();
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }



    WaveFormat GetWaveFormat(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int readBytes = 0, bytesReceived = 0;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        while ((readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            bytesReceived += readBytes;
            if (bytesReceived >= 10000) break;
        }
        req.Abort();
        resp.Close(); ms.Position = 0;
        WaveStream tempStream = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
        return tempStream.WaveFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Your interruption is probably because your computer needs to download the file.

Comment: This problem happens even if progress bar is on 50%,mp3 duration is 3 min or above and played duration is approximately 10 sec.

Comment: Every time you click the play button, the file is redownloaded. Make a new global boolean variable (`isDownloaded`). In your play button method, check if it's `false`. If it is, download, set it to `true`, and play. Otherwise, just play.